# How to select concatenated id from another table MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table for Menu and another table which contains the column Menus, the data in Menus is in one cell only

```
   Menu                             the other table(column)
Id | Name                                  Menus
1  | Cordon Bleu                           1,2
2  | Pork Chop
```

i would like to query the Menus(on the right) in a way that it would return Cordon Bleu, Pork Chop in one variable, any way to do this?
Thanks

Comment: i honestly have no idea how to do it :)

Answer (score 0):

you can use with field names that you are using :

```
SELECT * FROM menu as o LEFT JOIN menus as c ON o.id = c.menu WHERE you want
```

or you have to pass id to a php function that return the row with that id

Comment: the column Menus, has the id(1,2) in one cell

Comment: you can explode menus and for each id select the ids in table menu

Answer (score 0):

Try with -

```
select Name from Menu where Id IN (select Menus from other_table) // Add conditions to subquery if needed.
```